# Why do the string functions in C work on arrays with char instead of unsigned char?

Tags: c, string

In the `C` standard library functions, the elements of the strings are `char`s. Is there a good reason why it was decided instead of `unsigned char` ?

Using `unsigned char` for 8-bit strings has some, albeit small advantages:

- it is more intuitive, as we usually memorize ASCII codes as unsigned values, and when working on binary data, we prefer the range 0x00 to 0xFF, unsigned, instead of dealing with negative numbers. So we have to cast.
- working with unsigned integers might be faster/more effective, or generate smaller code on some processors.

Comment: Note that there are three character types:  `char`, `unsigned char`, and `signed char`.  `char` may be either signed or unsigned.

Comment: Actually, ASCII is only seven bits, 0 to 127. 128 to 255 is [extended ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_ASCII).

Comment: Your memorized ASCII codes fail when something different comes along.

Comment: Note that "working with unsigned integers might be faster/more effective, or generate smaller code on some processors" is not really an argument in favor of the standard using `unsigned char` for strings, because if it generates faster, smaller code on some processors, chances are it generates slower, larger code on others! It is an argument for permitting char to be unsigned, though, which is the actual situation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

C provides three different character types:

- `char` represents a character (which C also calls a "byte").
- `unsigned char` represents a byte-sized pattern of bits, or an unsigned integer.
- `signed char` represents a byte-sized signed integer.

It is implementation-defined whether `char` is a signed or an unsigned type, so I think the question amounts to either "why does `char` exist at all as this maybe-signed type?" or "why doesn't C require `char` to be unsigned?".

The first thing to know is that Ritchie added the "char" type to the B language in 1971, and C inherited it from there. Prior to that, B was word-oriented rather than byte-oriented ([so says the man himself](https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/chist.html), see "The Problems of B".)

With that done, the answer to both of my questions might be that early versions of C didn't have unsigned types.

Once `char` and the string-handling functions were established, changing them all to `unsigned char` would be a serious breaking change (i.e. almost all existing code would stop working), and one of the ways C has tried to cultivate its user-base over the decades is by mostly avoiding catastrophic incompatible changes. So it would be surprising for C to make that change.

Given that `char` is going to be the character type, and that (as you observe) it makes a lot of sense for it to be unsigned, but that plenty of implementations already existed in which char was signed, I suppose that making the signedness of char implementation-defined was a workable compromise -- existing code would continue working. Provided that it was using `char` only as a character and not for arithmetic or order comparisons, it would also be portable to implementations where `char` is unsigned.

Unlike some of C's age-old implementation-defined variations, implementers do still choose signed characters (Intel). The C standard committee cannot help but observe that some people seem to stick with signed characters for some reason. Whatever those people's reasons are, current or historical, C has to allow it because existing C implementations rely on it being allowed. So forcing `char` to be unsigned is far lower on the list of achievable goals than forcing `int` to be 2's complement, and C hasn't even done that.

A supplementary question is "why does Intel still specify `char` to be signed in its ABIs?", to which I don't know an answer but I'd guess that they've never had an opportunity to do otherwise without massive disruption. Maybe they even like them.

Answer (score 4):

Good question. As the standard does not define `char` to be either unsigned or signed (this is left to the implementation), I guess that the preference over `char` came combined from two angles:

- `char` takes less time to type than `unsigned char`, making the prototypes of the string manipulation functions nicer to read and use.
- Since the original ASCII spec was 7-bit, it didn't matter for the C spec's sake whether the valid values are in the range 0 to 127 or 0 to 255. Standardization of 8-bit characters sets has occurred much later.

Comment: "char takes less time to type than unsigned char". That doesn't explain why char isn't unsigned by default, however :)  I'm guessing it has to do with consistency to the other integer types: short, int, long, as those are always guaranteed to be signed by default.

Answer (score 4):

The signedness of `char` is implementation-defined.

A cleaner solution to the problem you're describing would be to mandate that plain `char` must be unsigned.

The reason plain `char` may be either signed or unsigned is partly historical, and partly related to performance.

Very early versions of C didn't have unsigned types. Since ASCII only covers the range 0 to 127, it was assumed that there was no particular disadvantage in making `char` a signed type. Once that decision was made, some programmers might have written code that depends on that, and later compilers kept `char` as a signed type to avoid breaking such code.

Quoting a [C Reference Manual](http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/who/dmr/cman.pdf) from 1975, 3 years before the publication of K&R1:

> Characters (declared, and hereinafter called, `char`) are chosen from
>   the ASCII set; they occupy the right- most seven bits of an 8-bit
>   byte. It is also possible to interpret `char`s as signed, 2’s complement
>   8-bit numbers.

EBCDIC requires 8-bit unsigned `char`, but apparently EBCDIC-based machines weren't yet supported at that time.

As for performance, values of type `char` are implicitly converted, in many contexts, to `int` (assuming that `int` can represent all values of type `char`, which is usually the case).  This is done via the "integer promotions".  For example, this:

```
char ch = '0';
ch ++;
```

doesn't just perform an 8-bit increment. It converts the value of `ch` from `char` to `int`, adds 1 to the result, and converts the sum back from `int` to `char` to store it in `ch`. (The compiler can generate any code that provably achieves the same effect.)

Converting an 8-bit signed `char` to a 32-bit signed `int` requires sign extension.  Converting an 8-bit unsigned `char` to a 32-bit signed `int` requires zero-filling the high-order 24 bits of the target. (The actual widths of these types may vary.) Depending on the CPU, one of these operations may be faster than the other. On some CPUs, making plain `char` signed might result in faster generated code.

(I don't know what the magnitude of this effect is.)

Comment: To be picky, c++ promotes char to int by the "integer promotion rules", even though those are part of "the usual arithmetic...".

Comment: @Lundin: To be equally picky, the question is tagged c, not c++.

Comment: "Since ASCII only covers the range 0 to 127, it was assumed that there was no particular disadvantage in making char a signed type" -- are you sure that follows? EBCDIC is 8-bit, are you in effect saying that it was never considered?

Comment: @SteveJessop: It probably wasn't considered in the very early days of C, before it was implemented on any EBCDIC-based systems. I'll update my answer in a moment.

Comment: @KeithThompson And...? The integer promotions/usual arithmetic conversions are 100% identical in C and C++. `c++` in my comment refers to your badly picked example `c ++`, not the language.

Comment: Fair enough, I don't actually know at what point Ritchie started thinking about C as a super-portable language rather than just a way to get things done on the couple of machines he cared about. Conceivably it was *after* other people started porting C to their machines, and complaining about his unacceptably ASCII-centric assumptions ;-)

Comment: @Lundin: I wasn't sure that C and C++ used the same terminology. I think they do, so you're right. (Not sure why you mentioned C++ in your initial comment, but that doesn't matter a whole lot.)

Comment: @Lundin: A few months later, looking back at the comments, I now realize that you were referring to the C expression `c++`, not to the C++ language (as you said). I probably should have chosen a better variable name. The confusion was my fault.

Comment: @Lundin: A few years later, I've finally updated this answer.

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no good reason. Nor is there any good reason why the signedness of char is implementation-defined. There exists no symbol table of any kind that uses negative number indexing.

I think all of this originates from the incorrect, weird assumption that there are 8 bit integers and then there are "characters", where "characters" is some sort of magical mysterious thing.

This is just one of many irrational flaws the C standard, inherited from the days when dinosaurs walked the earth. The mysterious signedness of char adds nothing to the language, except perhaps a potential for signedness-related bugs caused by implicit integer promotions.

**EDIT:**

Likely they let char be signed because they wanted it to behave just as the other integer types: short, int, long, which are all guaranteed by the standard to alwasy be signed by default.

> working with unsigned integers might be faster/more effective, or generate smaller code on some processors.

What type you end up with in the end isn't exactly intuitive. Whenever you use char as operand in an expression, it will always get promoted to int. Similarly, constant character literals 'a', '\n' etc are of type int, not char. The C language forces the compiler to promote the types according to the implicit promotion rules (known as "integer promotions" and "the usual arithmetic conversions"/"balancing").

Once that promotion is done, the compiler may optimize the type into the one that is most effective, if it can prove that the optimization doesn't change the result.

If you have this code:

```
char a = 'a';
char b = 'b';
char c = a + b;
```

there are many obscure things going on between the lines. First of all, the literals 'a' and 'b' get silently truncated from `int` into signed/unsigned char. Then in the expression `a + b`, both a and b are implicitly promoted by the integer promotion rules into `int` types. The addition is performed on two `int`. Then the result is silently truncated back into a signed/unsigned char.

If the compiler can prove that optimization does not affect any of the above obscurities, it may replace it all with sane, 8-bit operations.

Comment: It is also worth mentioning that MISRA-C bans the use of the "plain char" type for anything but string handling, just because of the unknown signedness issue.

Answer (score 3):

There are three related types:

- `signed char`, designed to store small signed integers
- `unsigned char`, designed to store small unsigned intergers
- `char`, designed to store characters

I think that what you really want to know is why isn't `char` an unsigned type?

There was a time when [C hadn't unsigned types](http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/who/dmr/cman.pdf)[1]. `char` were described as signed (see page 4), but even at that time, "the sign propagation feature disappears in other implementations", so it behaved already as signed at places, unsigned at other. And I think that the implementations choices simply reflected what was the easiest for them (for instance on the PDP-11, for which the first C implementation was made, `MOVB` did the sign extension and I don't remember there was a way to move a byte to a word without getting the sign extension).

Nowadays, most implementations I know are using signed `char`. The only one I know which have unsigned `char` are those from IBM were the support of EBCDIC mandate it (character codes for the characters in the basic character sets have to be positive, and EBCDIC has most of them above 128).

[1] [Pointers where used instead...](http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/who/dmr/chist.pdf)

Comment: There are many embedded systems compilers that make char unsigned by default.

Comment: Pretty much anything that targets ARM, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Because standard doesn't define char as signed char

Comment: but it could have defined string functions as `usnigned char`, I'm interested in reasons why that choice was not made. I mean, is there any advantage in not doing so?

Comment: @vsz Developers are by nature lazy, why go through all the work of writing `unsigned` when you don't have to? ;)

Comment: Implementation defines if char is signed or unsigned, is a matter of portability, think in char as an alias for byte